# Local web traffic using dynamic dns is not routing on my dd-wrt router

Tags: networking, router

My local network is handled using a wireless router flashed with DD-WRT. I have a wireless device on my local network whose web interface I've been exposing to the Internet via port forwarding. I setup a dynamic dns (DynDNS) entry for my local network and had been successfully routing both local and external traffic to the forwarded port via this dns name.

A recent upgrade of the router firmware broke this port forwarding. External networks can still use the dynamic dns name. Local clients using this dns name fail to route the internal device. Local traffic still routes via the local IP.

Comment: Does reverting to the previous version of DD-WRT resolve the issue? If so, it could be a bug in that particular release. It could also be that the old config didn't upgrade properly (despite what the GUI may say) – you could try to reset the config and start over.

Comment: The DD-WRT site does not have older versions of my firmware so I was not able to downgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around this problem editing the router's /etc/hosts file to include the external dns name for the device. There was no web UI for this so I had to enable SSH use vi the edit the /etc/hosts file.

I realize this is not the best solution but it worked for me.

Comment: I was hoping for another enlightened answer but since you suggested.. I'll do so tomorrow when the site will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

This ticket seems to be related: http://svn.dd-wrt.com:8000/ticket/1868

They give a solution but mark the ticket as "wonfix". I do not understand why either.